# openssh version shows differently internally and externally

Tags: ssh

I upgraded openssh-server from 5.9 to 6.5 on my Ubuntu 12.04.

```
# ssh -V => OpenSSH_6.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
```

But when I check that from remote

```
# telnet mydomain.com 22
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I installed the new version from source.
I guess that 2 different openssh is running.

How can I fixed this?

Thanks.

Sam

Here's the output of 'cat /etc/init.d/ssh':

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             sshd
# Required-Start:       $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:        $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description:    OpenBSD Secure Shell server
### END INIT INFO
set -e
# /etc/init.d/ssh: start and stop the OpenBSD "secure shell(tm)" daemon
test -x /usr/sbin/sshd || exit 0
( /usr/sbin/sshd -\? 2>&1 | grep -q OpenSSH ) 2>/dev/null || exit 0
chrooted() {
    # borrowed from udev's postinst
    # and then borrowed from initramfs-tools's preinst
    if [ "$(stat -c %d/%i /)" = "$(stat -Lc %d/%i /proc/1/root 2>/dev/null)" ]; then
        # the devicenumber/inode pair of / is the same as that of
        # /sbin/init's root, so we're *not* in a chroot and hence
        # return false.
        return 1
    fi
    return 0
}
# The init.d script is only for chroots
if [ -e /etc/init/ssh.conf ] && ! chrooted; then
    exec /lib/init/upstart-job ssh "$@"
fi
umask 022
if test -f /etc/default/ssh; then
    . /etc/default/ssh
fi
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
if [ -n "$2" ]; then
    SSHD_OPTS="$SSHD_OPTS $2"
fi
# Are we running from init?
run_by_init() {
    ([ "$previous" ] && [ "$runlevel" ]) || [ "$runlevel" = S ]
}
check_for_no_start() {
    # forget it if we're trying to start, and /etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run exists
    if [ -e /etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run ]; then
        if [ "$1" = log_end_msg ]; then
            log_end_msg 0 || true
        fi
        if ! run_by_init; then
            log_action_msg "OpenBSD Secure Shell server not in use (/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run)" || true
        fi
        exit 0
    fi
}
check_dev_null() {
    if [ ! -c /dev/null ]; then
        if [ "$1" = log_end_msg ]; then
            log_end_msg 1 || true
        fi
        if ! run_by_init; then
            log_action_msg "/dev/null is not a character device!" || true
        fi
        exit 1
    fi
}
check_privsep_dir() {
    # Create the PrivSep empty dir if necessary
    if [ ! -d /var/run/sshd ]; then
        mkdir /var/run/sshd
        chmod 0755 /var/run/sshd
    fi
}
check_config() {
    if [ ! -e /etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run ]; then
        /usr/sbin/sshd $SSHD_OPTS -t || exit 1
    fi
}
export PATH="${PATH:+$PATH:}/usr/sbin:/sbin"
case "$1" in
  start)
        check_privsep_dir
        check_for_no_start
        check_dev_null
        log_daemon_msg "Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server" "sshd" || true
        if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid --exec /usr/sbin/sshd -- $SSHD_OPTS; then
            log_end_msg 0 || true
        else
            log_end_msg 1 || true
        fi
        ;;
  stop)
        log_daemon_msg "Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server" "sshd" || true
        if start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid; then
            log_end_msg 0 || true
        else
            log_end_msg 1 || true
        fi
        ;;
  reload|force-reload)
        check_for_no_start
        check_config
        log_daemon_msg "Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server's configuration" "sshd" || true
        if start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid --exec /usr/sbin/sshd; then
            log_end_msg 0 || true
        else
            log_end_msg 1 || true
        fi
        ;;
  restart)
        check_privsep_dir
        check_config
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting OpenBSD Secure Shell server" "sshd" || true
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry 30 --pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid
        check_for_no_start log_end_msg
        check_dev_null log_end_msg
        if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid --exec /usr/sbin/sshd -- $SSHD_OPTS; then
            log_end_msg 0 || true
        else
            log_end_msg 1 || true
        fi
        ;;
  try-restart)
        check_privsep_dir
        check_config
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting OpenBSD Secure Shell server" "sshd" || true
        RET=0
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry 30 --pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid || RET="$?"
        case $RET in
            0)
                # old daemon stopped
                check_for_no_start log_end_msg
                check_dev_null log_end_msg
                if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid --exec /usr/sbin/sshd -- $SSHD_OPTS; then
                    log_end_msg 0 || true
                else
                    log_end_msg 1 || true
                fi
                ;;
            1)
                # daemon not running
                log_progress_msg "(not running)" || true
                log_end_msg 0 || true
                ;;
            *)
                # failed to stop
                log_progress_msg "(failed to stop)" || true
                log_end_msg 1 || true
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
  status)
        status_of_proc -p /var/run/sshd.pid /usr/sbin/sshd sshd && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
  *)
        log_action_msg "Usage: /etc/init.d/ssh {start|stop|reload|force-reload|restart|try-restart|status}" || true
        exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: Did you just perform this upgrade?  Did you restart the ssh server after you upgraded?.  `ssh -V` is the version of the client, not the version of the server.

Comment: Just run /etc/init.d/sshd restart as root.

Comment: @Zoredache I also checked with 'sshd -V' and it displayed OpenSSH_6.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012.

Comment: @FrediWeber I don't have that file. However, /etc/init.d/ssh exists.

Comment: Can you run 'which sshd'?

Comment: Are you certain you are actually connecting to your server and not some other device between you and the server?  Check your host keys.  Use `ssh-keyscan hostname/ip`.

Comment: @FrediWeber 'which sshd' shows /usr/local/sbin/sshd.

Comment: And whats in /etc/init.d/ssh? The same path?

Comment: @Zoredache I am not sure how to check it. Anyway I ran ssh-keyscan mydomain.com and it showed some long keys.

Comment: @FrediWeber /etc/init.d/ssh is a file. Its size is 4371.

Comment: Yes of course but could you run 'cat /etc/init.d/ssh'?

Comment: @FrediWeber I added the output above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have two versions of the ssh server installed.
One from Ubuntu which is installed under /usr/sbin/sshd
The newer one that was installed by you is located at /usr/local/sbin/sshd
So you need to change the startup script that it matches the new path or you replace the /usr/sbin/sshd with a symlink to /usr/local/sbin/sshd.

Comment: Fredi, your answer is very helpful. I really appreciate it. I'll replace /use/sbin/sshd with a symlink to /use/local/sbin/sshd. Is there a way to restart it without rebooting the server?

Comment: @SamKong please try to avoid installing custom software versions like this as it will invariably clutter up your system given time. IMHO its far superior using your own custom packages if you really have to build a custom version. Its not that hard, you should try it.

Comment: @ZaphodB Thank you for the advice. As you said, I abandoned the installation from source and I requested an exception for PCI network scan.

Comment: should the symlink work, afterwards I got kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer and could not connect? Luckily I kept a copy of sshd to restore it

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to restart the ssh server.

Comment: Yes. I restarted it.
sudo service ssh stop
sudo service ssh start

Answer (score 2):

Ok,
I would remove the new version of OpenSSH you installed via source. Upgrade SSH with the one  provided by Ubuntu.

To find the versions of ssh you have on your computer become root and run the command below.

```
find / -name ssh -type f 2>/dev/null
```

Then check the version of the output given. If you have one or more versions showing then you have more then on version installed.

Comment: Actually, that's what I wanted. But Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't have the latest version of openssh-server. The highest version is 5.9. That's why I had to install it from source. The PCI compliance requires us to upgrade openssh.

Comment: Be aware that many Linux distros have there own version numbers of OpenSSH and OpenSLL. I run into this all the time, when I harden the servers at work. If you are upgrading to harden your server, then I would go to the Ubuntu site and look up the security issue. They are usually tracked via CVE numbers.